# How to select the value of certain field from a table in a database, if the sum of the values from the given column does not exceed certain threshold?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Imagine there is an elevator which can hold a weight up to certain KG (kilogram). Now, consider a table in the database with the following columns: id, name, weight, turn - where the name represents the name of a person, weight represents the weight of that person (let's say in KG), and turn represents the position of the person waiting in the queue. How can one select the name of the last person who can enter the elevator considering the maximum weight the elevator can hold.

For example, considering the following values from the table named as INFO: 
(1, John 100, 1), (2, Jade, 80, 3), (3, Kate, 90, 2), (4, Bebe, 70, 4). If the maximum weight the elevator can hold is 200KG, the last person who can enter the elevator is "Kate" (the first person who enters the elevator is John considering the value of turn being "1", then "Kate" considering the value of turn being "2") - Johns' weight(100) + Kate's weight(90) = 190 (if we consider the next person, the limit is exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

You would use cumulative sums:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(weight) over (order by id) as running_weight
      from t
     ) t
where running_weight <= 200
order by id desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```